# Using SEF URLs breaks all templates

Tags: templates, sef, .htaccess-configuration, non-sef-url

I changed both **Search Engine Friendly URLs** to **Yes** and **Use URL Rewriting** to **Yes** in Global Configuration and **renamed the .htaccess.txt to .htaccess** .

But, now none of my templates work anymore.

**I have success in making the URLs cleaner** (removing the index.php from them), but the templates break. The links work without any problem.

I tried to follow some tutorials without success:

1. https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs_on_Apache
2. http://www.viryatechnologies.com/Virya-Blogs/joomla-content-management-system/2012/11/29/removing-indexphp-from-existing-sef-urls.html

I believe the mod_rewrite module is not the problem because the "new" links work properly.

The site is hosted in a webserver using Apache. The Joomla version is 3.6.5 .

Does anyone have any idea about what can be happening?

Comment: can you be more specific when you say the templates break? Got a screen shot? Also have you checked the console for errors when you load a broken page? Sounds like there may be a permission issue keeping the template resources from loading.

Comment: @BrianPeat, thank you for your answer. I already know what the problem was.
I am using the **JCH Optimize plugin.** In the Basic Options tab, there is a  **Use url rewrite** parameter. That was the problem.
When I switched it to off, the conflict stopped.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem:

The templates were not at all responsible.

I am using the **JCH Optimize plugin.** In the Basic Options tab, there is a **Use url rewrite parameter.** That was the problem. When I switched it to off, the conflict stopped.

For some reason, it does not work well with the directives inside my .htaccess file.